# Relationship between value of epoch and mini-batch and the total number of calculations

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model, gradient-descent

I've read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117919/what-are-the-differences-between-epoch-batch-and-minibatch) regarding the difference between `epoch` and `mini-batch`.

To clarify:

- With an `epoch` value of `1000` and `batch size` of `50`, does that mean that the model will use each data point exactly `1000` times in such an (random) order where at each iteration only `50` data points are used for optimization? (meaning a total of 50*1000 calculations?)
- Is *every* data point used *exactly* `1000` times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each iteration uses mini-batch number of points (here 50) and there will be 20 iterations in an epoch. An epoch ends when we go over all the training samples exactly once. This means every training point is used exactly 1000 times.

Comment: I see, so the number of iterations is `epoch / batch-size` and the number of total calculations is `epoch * number-of-points` (as each point is used to calculate the rate of change of error `epoch` amount of times?)

Comment: if by calculation you mean a training sample going through the alg, yes that’s correct

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: That's not true. 1 epoch means that 1 data point will be seen exactly one time (except there are duplicates in the dataset). So 50 epochs means that each datapoint is seen 50 times